# What are the possible Sigma Algebra of the set C = {1,2,3}

Tags: measure-theory

If C = {1,2,3} then these are the possible Sigma Algebra:

Let A = sigma algebra as it's easier to write.

A1 = {Ø, {1,2,3}}

A2 = {Ø, {1,2,3}, {1}, {2,3}, {2}, {1,3}, {3}, {1,2}}  - This is also the power set.

A3 = {Ø, {1,2,3}, {1}, {2,3}}

A4 = {Ø, {1,2,3}, {2}, {1,3}}

A5 = {Ø, {1,2,3}, {3}, {1,2}}

I checked these sets against the rules for a sigma algebra set and they all pass.

Questions:

A. Thus there are a total of 5 possible sigma algebra for set C.  Is this correct or am I missing sets?

B. The set {Ø, {1,2,3}, {1}, {2,3}, {2}, {1,3}} cannot be a sigma algebra set because {1} ∪ {2} = {1,2} and that is not part of this set.  Is this correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Looks good to me - as you may know $\sigma$-algebras are defined for at most countable operations, which include the finite examples you give (these are also examples of fields)